# Fedora client drops connection to SSL Server with "Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unknown CA)"

Tags: openssl, fedora, ssl

I am currently working in a web service to process payments from a web server running apache/fedora.
I sniffed the communication between client and server and got:

Client > Server: Cliente Hello

Server > Client: Server Hello

Server > Client: Certificate, Server Hello Done

Client > Server: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unknown CA)

then, the TCP connection is turn down.

Server address is https://secure.internetsecure.com/process.cgi

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your client is set to trust every certificate authority in the trust chain (in your case, the VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority and the VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA). Your client is erroring out because it doesn't know about these two certificates.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! It has sense. Do you have any link with info that explains how to do that? I am sorry, but I am new to SSL.